# Click one element add/remove class from another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problems getting my javascript to work. When the user clicks on the navigation items (in this case inputs), an "active" class gets added to the corresponding slide. Here is the code I currently am using:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slide'+ (i+1)) +.click(function(event){
        //remove all pre-existing active classes
        $('.top').removeClass('active');

        //add the active class to the link we clicked
        $(this).addClass('active');

    });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.inner {
  width: 500%;
  line-height: 0;
}


article {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

article img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-dot-control {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 110%;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-dot-control label {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #bbb;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.slider-dot-control label:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  border-color: #777;
}


/* Top Layer */
.top {
  position: absolute;
}


@keyframes top {
  from { top: 0; right: -250px; }
  to   { top: 0; right: 100px; }
}

.active {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: top;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}




/* Slider Styling */
.slider-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}

.slider-wrapper .inner {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 800ms;
  -moz-transition: all 800ms;
  transition: all 800ms;
}



/*---- SET POSITION FOR SLIDE ----*/
#slide1:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(2)::after, #slide2:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(3)::after, #slide3:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(4)::after, #slide4:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(5)::after, #slide5:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(1)::after, #slide2:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(1)::after, #slide3:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(2)::after, #slide4:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(3)::after, #slide5:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(4)::after, #slide1:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(5)::after {
  display: block;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(2)::after, #slide2:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(3)::after, #slide3:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(4)::after, #slide4:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(5)::after, #slide5:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(1)::after {
  content: "\f105";
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(2), #slide2:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(3), #slide3:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(4), #slide4:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(5), #slide5:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}


#slide2:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(1), #slide3:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(2), #slide4:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(3), #slide5:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(4), #slide1:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(5) {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#slide2:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(1)::after, #slide3:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(2)::after, #slide4:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(3)::after, #slide5:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(4)::after, #slide1:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(5)::after {
  content: "\f104";
  padding-left: 8px;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .slider-dot-control label:nth-child(1), #slide2:checked ~ .slider-dot-control label:nth-child(2), #slide3:checked ~ .slider-dot-control label:nth-child(3), #slide4:checked ~ .slider-dot-control label:nth-child(4), #slide5:checked ~ .slider-dot-control label:nth-child(5) {
  background: #333;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .slider-wrapper article:nth-child(1) .top, #slide2:checked ~ .slider-wrapper article:nth-child(2) .top, #slide3:checked ~ .slider-wrapper article:nth-child(3) .top, #slide4:checked ~ .slider-wrapper article:nth-child(4) .top, #slide5:checked ~ .slider-wrapper article:nth-child(5) .top {
  opacity: 1;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .slider-wrapper .inner {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

#slide2:checked ~ .slider-wrapper .inner {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#slide3:checked ~ .slider-wrapper .inner {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

#slide4:checked ~ .slider-wrapper .inner {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

#slide5:checked ~ .slider-wrapper .inner {
  margin-left: -400%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <input checked type=radio name="slider" id="slide1" />
    <input type=radio name="slider" id="slide2" />
    <input type=radio name="slider" id="slide3" />
    <input type=radio name="slider" id="slide4" />
    <input type=radio name="slider" id="slide5" />
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <div class="inner">
        <article>
          <div class="top active">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x150/ff0000">
          </div>
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        </article>
        <article>
          <div class="top">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x150/ff0000">
          </div>
          <img class="bkg-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        </article>
        <article>
          <div class="top">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x150/ff0000">
          </div>
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        </article>
        <article>
          <div class="top">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x150/ff0000">
          </div>
          <img class="bkg-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        </article>
        <article>
          <div class="top">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x150/ff0000">
          </div>
          <img class="bkg-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        </article>
    </div>
    <!-- .inner -->
  </div>
  <!-- .slider-wrapper -->
  

  <div class="slider-dot-control">
    <label for=slide1></label>
    <label for=slide2></label>
    <label for=slide3></label>
    <label for=slide4></label>
    <label for=slide5></label>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: `$('#slide'+ (i+1)) +.click`   <--- that is wrong.... why is there a `+`. You do not define `i`

Comment: Didn't you see the syntax error in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, `i` on your click event is undefined. Since your radio buttons have different ids its better to use class or button name for click event. And next thing you have added `active` class to clicked element with `$(this).addClass('active');` i.e you have added `active` class to radio button. Here, you need change your code, I have added `$('.slider-wrapper').find('article').eq($(this).index()).find('.top').addClass('active');` It will add active class to `top` selector of `article` element which has and index equal to clicked element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[name="slider"]').click(function(event){
       //remove all pre-existing active classes
       $('.top').removeClass('active');

       //add the active class to the link we clicked
       $('.slider-wrapper').find('article').eq($(this).index()).find('.top').addClass('active');

   });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.inner {
  width: 500%;
  line-height: 0;
}


article {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

article img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-dot-control {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 110%;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-dot-control label {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #bbb;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.slider-dot-control label:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  border-color: #777;
}


/* Top Layer */
.top {
  position: absolute;
}


@keyframes top {
  from { top: 0; right: -250px; }
  to   { top: 0; right: 100px; }
}

.active {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: top;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}




/* Slider Styling */
.slider-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}

.slider-wrapper .inner {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 800ms;
  -moz-transition: all 800ms;
  transition: all 800ms;
}



/*---- SET POSITION FOR SLIDE ----*/
#slide1:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(2)::after, #slide2:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(3)::after, #slide3:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(4)::after, #slide4:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(5)::after, #slide5:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(1)::after, #slide2:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(1)::after, #slide3:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(2)::after, #slide4:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(3)::after, #slide5:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(4)::after, #slide1:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(5)::after {
  display: block;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(2)::after, #slide2:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(3)::after, #slide3:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(4)::after, #slide4:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(5)::after, #slide5:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(1)::after {
  content: "\f105";
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(2), #slide2:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(3), #slide3:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(4), #slide4:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(5), #slide5:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}


#slide2:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(1), #slide3:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(2), #slide4:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(3), #slide5:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(4), #slide1:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(5) {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#slide2:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(1)::after, #slide3:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(2)::after, #slide4:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(3)::after, #slide5:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(4)::after, #slide1:checked ~ .slider-prev-next-control label:nth-child(5)::after {
  content: "\f104";
  padding-left: 8px;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .slider-dot-control label:nth-child(1), #slide2:checked ~ .slider-dot-control label:nth-child(2), #slide3:checked ~ .slider-dot-control label:nth-child(3), #slide4:checked ~ .slider-dot-control label:nth-child(4), #slide5:checked ~ .slider-dot-control label:nth-child(5) {
  background: #333;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .slider-wrapper article:nth-child(1) .top, #slide2:checked ~ .slider-wrapper article:nth-child(2) .top, #slide3:checked ~ .slider-wrapper article:nth-child(3) .top, #slide4:checked ~ .slider-wrapper article:nth-child(4) .top, #slide5:checked ~ .slider-wrapper article:nth-child(5) .top {
  opacity: 1;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .slider-wrapper .inner {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

#slide2:checked ~ .slider-wrapper .inner {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#slide3:checked ~ .slider-wrapper .inner {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

#slide4:checked ~ .slider-wrapper .inner {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

#slide5:checked ~ .slider-wrapper .inner {
  margin-left: -400%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <input checked type=radio name="slider" id="slide1" />
    <input type=radio name="slider" id="slide2" />
    <input type=radio name="slider" id="slide3" />
    <input type=radio name="slider" id="slide4" />
    <input type=radio name="slider" id="slide5" />
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <div class="inner">
        <article>
          <div class="top active">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x150/ff0000">
          </div>
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        </article>
        <article>
          <div class="top">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x150/ff0000">
          </div>
          <img class="bkg-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        </article>
        <article>
          <div class="top">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x150/ff0000">
          </div>
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        </article>
        <article>
          <div class="top">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x150/ff0000">
          </div>
          <img class="bkg-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        </article>
        <article>
          <div class="top">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x150/ff0000">
          </div>
          <img class="bkg-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        </article>
    </div>
    <!-- .inner -->
  </div>
  <!-- .slider-wrapper -->
  

  <div class="slider-dot-control">
    <label for=slide1></label>
    <label for=slide2></label>
    <label for=slide3></label>
    <label for=slide4></label>
    <label for=slide5></label>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `+` before `.click` and change your code to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#slide'+ (i+1)).click(function(event){
       //remove all pre-existing active classes
       $('.top').removeClass('active');

       //add the active class to the link we clicked
       $(this).addClass('active');

   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated the code but am not getting the expected behavior. Slides are getting that slide animation effect so I think they are not getting the "active" class passed to them on click. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zcm2w6e1/12/